# JavaFX: how to set a value of a Label to a system property in fxml?

Tags: javafx, fxml

In my application I defined the GUI in FXML. There is a label that always show the version of java. Is it possible to make it show this information without coding it in the controller?

I am thinking something like this:

```
<Label fx:id="info" fx:value="$java.version"/>
```

But this of course does not work. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want to set it via controller class.
Then you can utilize javascripting feature of FXML:

```
<?language javascript?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="my.FXMLDocumentController">
    <fx:script>
        var myText = 'version: ' + java.lang.System.getProperty('java.version');
    </fx:script>
    <children>
        <Label text="$myText" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```